# Python: Get current working directory from terminal

Tags: python, terminal, directory, operating-system

Hello I'm writing a small script which will make a webbsite template for me. I'm going to make an alias which would run the script and thats why I have a problem. When running the script, I don't want to write a directory to where I want to create my folder. I want it to create in my **terminals** working directory. How do I *"os.chdir()"* to my terminals working directory.
I have tried:

```py
import os
dir_path = os.system("pwd | clip")
os.chdir(dir_path)

Output:
TypeError: chdir: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not int
```

TL,DR
I want to get the path from where in terminal the script executes and then *os.chdir()* to it

Comment: "The terminal's working directory" will be the *initial* value for the script's working directory. If you haven't already changed this with `os.chdir()`, then there is no need to do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get current working dir:

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
```

Get the dir of the file you are executing from:

```
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

You can manipulate the string with e.g. `dir_path = os.path.join(dir_path, '..', 'somefolder')`.
With the resulting string you can do `os.chdir(dir_path)`